# Why doesn't defroi procedure work on MacOs?

Tags: idl, roi

I am working with IDL on MacOS and can't make the defroi procedure work. I can open up the window to define my ROI, but it is unable to mark anything in the image. I tried this exact code on a Windows and it works perfectly fine.
What am I doing wrong?

```
Seg=fix(Read_Binary(file, data_dims=dataDims, data_type=data, ENDIAN=little))

res=bytarr(512,512)+1
seg_tot=fltarr(512,512,154)
window,xsize=512,ysize=512
TvScl, total(Seg,3)
roi=defroi(512,512)
res[roi]=0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your X11 settings and under window activate ''click through inactive windows''. This should do the work.

Comment: Thank you! This was the solution.